# Differences between HPDI and PI intervals

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, credible-interval, highest-density-region

In Bayesian statistics, we may want to determine at what interval for example 95% of the posterior probability exists. For this we may want to use the Highest Posterior Density Interval (HPDI) which is [1]:

> The HPDI is the narrowest interval containing the specified
> probability mass. If you think about it, there must be an infinite
> number of posterior intervals with the same mass. But if you want an
> interval that best represents the parameter values most consistent
> with the data, then you want the densest of these intervals. That’s
> what the HPDI is.

Or the Percentile Intervals (PI) [1]:

> Intervals of this sort, which assign equal probability mass to each
> tail, are very common in the scientific literature.

Richard McElreath mentions that HPDI has some advantages over PI, but HPDI is more computationally intensive than PI and suffers from greater simulation variance. So both have their advantages and disadvantages. But PI mainly works well if the distribution isn't too asymmetrical, which in practice is most of the time the case, right?

So I was wondering if anyone could explain and show in what situation you would prefer to use `PI` over `HPDI` when computational intensity doesn't matter?

---

Reference:

- Statistical Rethinking, Richard McElreath [1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0<\alpha <1$, a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ credible set for the parameter $\theta$ based on data $x$ is a subset $C\subset\Theta$ such that
$$
P\{C|X = x\} = 1-\alpha.
$$
Usually, $C$ is taken to be an interval. Indeed, in the case of $\theta$ being a continuous random variable, letting $\theta^{(1)}, \theta^{(2)}$ be $100\alpha_1\%$ and $100(1-\alpha_2)\%$ quantiles with $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=\alpha$, $C = [\theta^{(1)}, \theta^{(2)}]$ is such an interval since
$P\{C|X=x\} = 1-\alpha.$ Usually equal-tailed intervals are chosen so $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha/2$.

However, as you noted,  the equal-tailed credible interval need not have the smallest size, namely length or area or volume whichever is appropriate. For that, one needs an HPD (Highest Posterior Density) interval.

Formally, an HPD is defined as follows. Let $\theta$ have a unimodal posterior density. Then the HPD interval for $\theta$ is the interval
$$
C = \{\theta:\pi(\theta|X=x)\geq k\},
$$
where $k$ is chosen such that

$$
P\{C | X=x\} = 1-\alpha.
$$

What is nice about HPDs is that they easily generalize to a vector $\theta$. In such a case, we talk about HPD credible sets. In the multivariate case indeed, credible sets based on quantiles are not easily adopted.

Clearly, in symmetric posterior distributions, HPD and quantile-based credible intervals coincide. Anyway, whatever the shape of the posterior distribution,

> credible intervals are easier to compute than HPDs

and

> HPDs have a smaller size that their quantile-based counterparts

are IMHO the only compelling reasons for their respective choice for practical use.